# MongoDB Unable to determine the serialization information

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I'm having a problem with Mongodb querying.
Here's the classes:

```
    class A
    { 

    }
    class B : A
    { 

    }
    class C : A
    {
        public string prop1 { get; set; }
    }
    class D
    {
        public List<A> collection1 { get; set; }
    }
```

And the query:

```
   var query1 = Query<D>.ElemMatch(d => d.collection1.OfType<C>(), 
             builder => builder.EQ(c => c.prop1, "val1"));
```

In a nutshell I want to select all instances of class D whose collection "collection1" contains at least one instance of class C whose property "prop1" equals "val1".

This keeps throwing "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression" out of the blue.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried decorating "A" with BsonKnownTypes(typeof(B), typeof(C)) to no avail.

PS: if I had only one class A:

```
    class A
    { 
        public string prop1 { get; set; }
    }
    class D
    {
        public List<A> collection1 { get; set; }
    }
```

then this code works and does exactly what I want:

```
   var query1 = Query<D>.ElemMatch(d => d.collection1, 
             builder => builder.EQ(c => c.prop1, "val1"));
```

but it's not what I want, I want to keep "B" and "C" that inherit from "A".

Comment: This isn't a full answer, hence the comment. The first parameter of ElemMatch here is just the property/field... You have added an OfType in there, so we have no idea what you are wanting. I need to think about the next part, but that's a little bit of the problem.

Comment: I want to consider only those documents from "collection1" that are of the "C" type. Hence the "OfType" (to filter out all those documents that are of the "B" type)
Anyway, that's how I would solve this problem in EF for example, but here it's throwing an exception...

Comment: Yeah, I get your intent. I'm saying that the first parameter isn't a predicate but rather an indicator of the field you want to apply the $elemMatch operator against. OfType can't be mapped to a field.

How to get the predicate in there is the second problem that can be solved with $and I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `nameof()`.

```
builder => builder.EQ(nameof(C.prop1), "val1");
```